# How do I set a different UITabBar.tintColor for every icon when selected?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 icons. I want them to have a different "highlight" color when selected.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `viewWillAppear` in the presentedVC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

In the other ones, just do a different color.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it manually:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [yourTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-unselected"];
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-selected"];

[tabBarItem setImage: [unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem setSelectedImage: selectedImage];
```